# If $f$ is a linear function such that $f(1, 2) = 0$ and $f(2, 3) = 1$, then what is $f(x, y)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> If $f$ is a linear function such that $f(1, 2) = 0$ and $f(2, 3) = 1$, then what is $f(x, y)$?

Any help is well received.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A linear function is of the form $f(x,y)=ax+by$.

We have $f(1,2)=a+2b=0$

We have $f(2,3)=2a+3b=1$.

We let $2a+4b=0$.

Therefore, $b=-1$, and $a=2$.

So $\boxed{f(x,y)=2x-y}$.

---

Update:

A linear function is of the form $f(x,y)=ax+by+c$

We have $f(1,2)=a+2b=-c$

We have $f(2,3)=2a+3b=1-c$.

We let $2a+4b=-2c$.

Therefore, $b=c-1$, so $a + 2(c-1)=-c$, and $a = -c+2(1-c)=2-3c$.

So $\displaystyle \boxed{f(x,y)=(2-3c)x-(c-1)y+c }$ for an arbitrary c.

**UPDATE**

The second piece is incorrect *in this context.* . AS @Clement C. adds, the arbitrary constant is zero, so that we do not have an unsolvable, affine function.

Comment: On second thought, there could be a +C

Comment: No, with a constant term that'd be referred to as an affine function (and the problem couldn't be solved).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $\{(1,2),(2,3)\}$ forms a basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(( x,y))=f (x (1,0)+y (0,1)) $$
$$=xf ((1,0))+yf ((0,1)) $$

so you need find $f ((1,0)) $ and $f ((0,1)) $ using

$f ((1,2))=0$ and $f ((2,3))=1$

$$2f (1,2)-f (2,3)=f (0,1)=-1$$

$$f (2,3)-f (1,2)=f (1,0)+f (0,1)=1$$
$$\implies f (1,0)=2$$

finally

> $$f (x,y)=2x-y$$

Comment: very interesting :)

Comment: @Leox Thanks. i am happy that people  like you exist.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you refer to a function *f* from the real plane to the real line, then note that `(1,2);(2,3)` is a base for the real pane vector space. Then any element of the plane can be represented as a linear combination of this elements. The applying linearity you get form for the required function.